# Set same panel height from another panel height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, panel

I have defined two panels each one inside a col-md-6 class like this. One of the panels will contain a map from google maps API, while the second panel has information about the map in a table. I want the first panel to have the same height of the second panel, because the map size I am using is fixed (e.g 250px), otherwise the map has height 0. My panels look like this:

```
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="panel panel-default">
             <div class="panel-heading">
                 <h3 class="panel-title">Panel 1</h3>
             </div>
             <div class="panel-body">
                  <div id="map" style="width: 100%;height: 250px"></div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="panel panel-default">
             <div class="panel-heading">
                 <h3 class="panel-title">Panel 2</h3>
             </div>
             <div class="panel-body">
                  A table
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery for this:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Panel 1</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="map"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default panel-info">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Panel 2</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        A table with content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var panelHeight = $('.panel-info .panel-body').height();
  $('#map').css('height', panelHeight);
});

$(window).resize(function () {
  var panelHeight = $('.panel-info .panel-body').height();
  $('#map').css('height', panelHeight);
});
```

Comment: I just changed the selector from .panel-info to .panel-info .panel-body because the most accurate height comes from the content of the panel and not the whole panel itself, but your solution is correct!